# Elasticsearch Params creation having SQL JOINs

Tags: elasticsearch, join

I am facing an issue with a relatively complex SQL query where I need to join multiple tables.

I am new to Elasticsearch and my first task with it has JOINs. Hence, I am seeking help to build Elasticsearch Params preferably in PHP (Although any mode would be appreciated).

I have (tables: fields) as follows:-

Books: id, title, Author_id, genre_id, description, ISBN, published_date, publisher_id
Authors: id, name
Genres: id, name
Publishers: id, name

These tables are related to the foreign key constraint.
Indices implemented on the following fields:
title, auther_id, genre_id, ISBN, published_date, publisher_id

I tried searching many resources online regarding the issue but only found Elastic params for simple queries that don't match my requirement. I also tried reading the official document but it is overwhelming for newbies. Hence, I need guidance from experienced to guide me on how params can be structured.

Comment: What does this have to do with MySQL? JOIN is a generic relational database concept, not specific to MySQL.

Comment: Maybe ElasticSearch param structure varies based on RDBMS. I don't know.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: it's pretty confusing.  you have a problem with mysql and talk about elasticsearch and query with Join.  maybe this question is tagged incorrectly.

Comment: I want Elasticsearch params for my SQL query. I need help from someone who has experience with Elasticsearch with complex queries.